# Can't push gem to the right link

Tags: ruby, github, rubygems

So I've already built my gem but when I try to push it, it goes directly to Github instead of rubygems.org:

```
> gem push my-gem.gem  
> Pushing gem to https://github.com/User/my-gem...
> Cookies must be enabled to use GitHub.
```

I've already set up the rubygems link on my gemspec, but nothing chages.
How can I fix that?
Here's my gemspec file:

```
require_relative 'lib/Mygem/version'

Gem::Specification.new do |spec|
  spec.name          = "Mygem"
  spec.version       = Mygem::VERSION
  spec.authors       = ["Me"]
  spec.email         = ["email@email.com"]

  spec.summary       = "Created gem"
  spec.description   = "Gem utility"
  spec.homepage      = "https://rubygems.org"
  spec.license       = "MIT"
  spec.required_ruby_version = Gem::Requirement.new(">= 2.3.0")

  spec.metadata["allowed_push_host"] = "https://rubygems.org"

  spec.metadata["homepage_uri"] = spec.homepage
  
  spec.files         = Dir.chdir(File.expand_path('..', __FILE__)) do
    `git ls-files -z`.split("\x0").reject { |f| f.match(%r{^(test|spec|features)/}) }
  end
  spec.bindir        = "exe"
  spec.executables   = spec.files.grep(%r{^exe/}) { |f| File.basename(f) }
  spec.require_paths = ["lib"]
  spec.add_development_dependency "bundler", "~> 2.0"
  spec.add_development_dependency "rake", "~> 13.0"
  spec.add_development_dependency "rspec", "~> 3.0"
end
```

Comment: Can you show your gemspec file?

Comment: @SonDang Sure, there it is.